# Sphinx rotate index terminal Command not working with php exec

Tags: php, centos, sphinx

The following sphinx index rotate command is working in my centos terminal.

```
echo "<password>" | sudo -S /usr/bin/indexer --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf gplay --rotate
```

But when i try to execute the same using "exec" php command is not working,

```
$output = exec('echo "S5evUna#" | sudo -S /usr/bin/indexer --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf gplay --rotate', $output);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

The output is empty here.

Please suggest any idea on this

Comment: Please check apache error logs if you are executing your PHP script from the web. Also, PHP will be executed by Apache user if you are accessing it via browser and in that case, you need to put apache user in sudoers file

Comment: Yes. But i have changed the searchd and indexer to the "apache" user. Still it is not working and i dont know change the sudoers file.

Comment: In your command, redirect standard error and output to some file and check the error

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. in the file, i see the error "WARNING: failed to open pid_file '/usr/local/sphinx/log/searchd.pid'."

Comment: Seems permission issues, where apache/php is not able to write/create pid file

Comment: And also we found that searchd.pid file in "sphinx" user. So we have changed that into apache user. but we got the same error.

Comment: apache user does not have enough permission to write /usr/local/sphinx/log directory, just give full permission to /usr/local/sphinx/log directory (which is not advisable)

Comment: But the log folder is in full permission: drwxrwxrwx